I can't get middleware stacking to work on next14 app router (for i18 and auth)
I'm working on a next14 project, I currently have middleware set for i18 and am trying to add a second middleware for authentication using auth.js (next-auth).
I've now gotten both middleware to work (i think?) but it looks like props are missing from my locale middleware.
Here's a github gist with all my code related to middlewares, including the file's location and any errors that are present in any file: code
in the screenshots below you can find the errors that nextjs is throwing.


in localeMiddleware.ts, when logging, I get the following results:

console.log(request) -> [Function]
console.log(request.nextUrl) -> undefined

The locale middleware by itself worked, with no errors, so I don't think there's anything wrong with my code there, but I guess I could be wrong...
Should I be passing props to the individual middleware files somehow?
Also, is there any way I can check that the middleware work as expected?

Pulling a conversation from Discord into SO.... Having a single middleware is probably the best solution with some
 
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/about')) {
    // This logic is only applied to /about
  }
 
  if (request.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/dashboard')) {
    // This logic is only applied to /dashboard
  }
}


All of the code above is useless and obsolete - I should just have added more functions for each additional middleware I wanted, in the original middleware.ts file, making sure to pass the request object in each function
simple as that.
